# Why is the subquery inside an iif affecting results?

Tags: visual-foxpro

3 example queries:

```
SELECT Pl_dscs.cid;
FROM itfwarehouse!pl_dscs;
INNER JOIN itfwarehouse!nonbaggedsys_descs ON Pl_dscs.cnonbaggedsys_descs_id = nonbaggedsys_descs.cid;
WHERE PL_dscs.cnonbaggedsys_descs_id = lcnbsdcid AND;
    iif(.f.,pl_dscs.ldiscontinued=.f.,.t.) AND;
    iif(.f.,.t.,.t.) INTO CURSOR lcresult

SELECT Pl_dscs.cid;
FROM itfwarehouse!pl_dscs;
INNER JOIN itfwarehouse!nonbaggedsys_descs ON Pl_dscs.cnonbaggedsys_descs_id = nonbaggedsys_descs.cid;
WHERE PL_dscs.cnonbaggedsys_descs_id = lcnbsdcid AND;
    iif(.f.,pl_dscs.ldiscontinued=.f.,.t.) AND;
    iif(.f.,.f.,.t.) INTO CURSOR lcresult

SELECT Pl_dscs.cid;
FROM itfwarehouse!pl_dscs;
INNER JOIN itfwarehouse!nonbaggedsys_descs ON Pl_dscs.cnonbaggedsys_descs_id = nonbaggedsys_descs.cid;
WHERE PL_dscs.cnonbaggedsys_descs_id = lcnbsdcid AND;
    iif(.f.,pl_dscs.ldiscontinued=.f.,.t.) AND;
    iif(.f.,NOT pl_dscs.cid in (select cpl_dscs_id FROM itfwarehouse!pl_dscsperfacwsite WHERE pl_dscsperfacwsite.cfacilities_id = ""),.t.) INTO CURSOR lcresult
```

This is all about the difference between the 2nd example and the 3rd example.

- The 1st example returns 1 record
- The 2nd example returns 1 record
- The 3rd example does not return any records

The only difference between the 2nd and 3rd examples is the 2nd expression in the last iif is a subquery. Because the 1st expression in that iif is false, the subquery should not get executed. Obviously it is somehow effecting the results but how/why?

Thanks,
John

Comment: Do you know for certain that the truth value of ".f" is False? If it's True, the conditions are just different. Don't know visual-foxpro, but just assuming this is a boolean column.

Comment: Hi Marc, Yes in VFP .f. is truly a False value

Comment: It is indeed strange. The way VFP works, it shouldn't be evaluated. Unfortunately I don't have access to a machine where I can try this in VFP for now. I will try to reproduce later. BTW, maybe you should remove the SQL tag, so those who don't know VFP wouldn't attempt to close your question. Unfortunately people on SO prefer to close questions that they don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

OK I could check this on my work machine and I think you found a bug. Since we know that it would never get corrected, here is a workaround for you, instead of using IIF(), use expressions that mimic IIF() - I never liked the idea of using IIF() in a where clause anyway:

```
LOCAL llState
llState = .F.

SELECT Pl_dscs.cid;
FROM itfwarehouse!pl_dscs;
INNER JOIN itfwarehouse!nonbaggedsys_descs ON Pl_dscs.cnonbaggedsys_descs_id = nonbaggedsys_descs.cid;
WHERE PL_dscs.cnonbaggedsys_descs_id = lcnbsdcid AND;
    ((m.llState AND pl_dscs.ldiscontinued=.f.) OR (!m.llState AND .T.)) ;
    ((m.llState AND ;
        pl_dscs.cid NOT in ;
        (select cpl_dscs_id ;
        FROM itfwarehouse!pl_dscsperfacwsite ;
        WHERE pl_dscsperfacwsite.cfacilities_id = "");
    ) OR  (!m.llState AND .T.)) ;
INTO CURSOR lcresult ;
NOFILTER
```

As per the bug itself with reproduction (and workaround):

```
 LOCAL state
state = .F.

Select c.Cust_id, c.Country, o.Order_id ;
    FROM _samples+'data\Customer' c ;
    inner Join _samples+'data\Orders' o On c.cust_id = o.cust_id ;
    where c.Country = 'USA' And ;
    IIF(m.state, ;
        c.Cust_id NOT in (SELECT cust_id FROM _samples+'data\Customer' WHERE Country = 'USA' AND MaxOrdAmt > 1000) ;
        ,.T.) ; 
    ORDER BY c.Country, c.Cust_id, o.Order_id ;
    INTO Cursor crsResult ;
    nofilter


Select crsResult
Browse


Select c.Cust_id, c.Country, o.Order_id ;
    FROM _samples+'data\Customer' c ;
    inner Join _samples+'data\Orders' o On c.cust_id = o.cust_id ;
    where c.Country = 'USA' And ;
    ((m.state AND ;
        c.Cust_id NOT in (SELECT cust_id FROM _samples+'data\Customer' WHERE Country = 'USA' AND MaxOrdAmt > 1000)) ;
        OR ;
     (!m.state AND .T.)) ; 
    ORDER BY c.Country, c.Cust_id, o.Order_id ;
    INTO Cursor crsResult ;
    nofilter


Select crsResult
Browse
```

With IIF(), it is kind of (but not exact) creating a cross join with the subquery.